# Do the functor laws prove complete preservation of structure?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

In the documenation for [Data.Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Functor.html) the following two are stated as the functor laws, which all functors should adhere to.

```
fmap id  ==  id
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g
```

The way my *intuition* tells me functors should work is that they should be "structure preserving", or in other words, if you have a function `f :: a -> b` and it's inverse `g :: b -> a` then

```
fmap f . fmap g  ==  id
```

I have not been able to come up with an implementation of `fmap` that would adhere to the first two laws and violate the second, but that's hardly proof. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: +1 I have been grappling with similar questions lately. There is one thing that bothers me with this intuitive formulation: what about functions without inverses? Surely `fmap (const "Foo")` is structure-preserving too in some sense?

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `const "Foo"` to prove the law true – you have to pick another function. I'm not saying functors are only valid for the kinds of functions the law encompasses.

Comment: @duplode imagine a tree `data Tree a = Leaf | Node a [Tree a]`. When we talk about "structure" of `t :: Tree a` we think of how many subtrees does each node have and how these subtrees are arranged. So you might say we are interested in `t` with _anything in its nodes_. And indeed we can capture that with `fmap (const ()) t`.

Comment: @fizruk Indeed; for this `Tree` type that is what is at play when we talk about, to use kqr's phrasing, "complete preservation of structure". The issue is: can you prove such preservation starting from the functor laws alone? Or it only makes sense to speak of "structure" when you are dealing with concrete functors?

Comment: @duplode the functor laws _define_ structure preservation property of a functor, you don't prove it from the laws.

Comment: @fizruk Oops, I think I'm muddling the waters, and possibly should ask a separate question. There seem to be two meanings of "structure" at play here: the categorical structure, which functors preserve by definition, and the concrete structure of e.g. a tree. kqr was talking about the first meaning, while I am mostly concerned with the second one.

Comment: I just want to point out for future Google people that [this blog post](http://duplode.github.io/posts/what-does-fmap-preserve.html) does a really good job of convincing me that structure is preserved, and even goes further than that!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, your "third" functor law follows directly from actual functor laws and the fact that `f . g ≡ id`:

```
fmap f . fmap g ≡ fmap (f . g) ≡ fmap id ≡ id
```

And there's more: Haskell ensures that if first law holds for `Functor` instance, then the second one also holds (this is a free theorem for the type of `fmap`). I.e. you have to prove only `fmap id ≡ id` law for your `Functor` instance to ensure that it is valid.

Comment: When `f . g ≡ id`, does both the function `f` and `g` have any mathematical term describing their relationship ? (I think I read about isomorphism somewhere, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Sibi: why, yes, `f` is a left inverse of `g` and `g` is a right inverse of `f`. That doesn't imply isomorphism of domain and codomain of either of the functions though, for instance `show :: Int -> String` has `read` as a left inverse, though `Int` obviously has smaller cardinality than `String`.

Comment: @Sibi Note that `f . g ≡ id` does not imply `g . f ≡ id`. However, if it is the case then both functions are called _"isomorphisms"_. Otherwise, `f` is called _"retraction"_ (or _"left inverse of `g`"_) and `g` is called _"section"_ (or _"right inverse of `f`"_).

Comment: I see it now, thanks. I was for somehow trying to reason the other way around, and couldn't quite convince myself. I think the main thing that tripped me up was that the functions I tried with that I thought were inverses to each other weren't actually inverses.