# Why doesn't inverse function imply isomorphism

Tags: haskell, isomorphism

Let's say I have two functions named `f :: a -> b` and it's inverse `g :: b -> a` such that `f . g ≡ id`.

Now isn't `g . f ≡ id` ? (And hence implying isomorphism)

I tried to write a similar example and came up with this:

```
myRead :: String -> Int
myRead = read

myShow :: Int -> String
myShow = show
```

In ghci:

```
λ> myRead . myShow $ 3
3
λ> myShow . myRead $ "33"
"33"
```

But it seems that the [inverse function doesn't imply isomorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675434/do-the-functor-laws-prove-complete-preservation-of-structure#comment36372692_23675541). So can anybody point me on what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Consider converting `Float` and `Int` to each other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a really trivial example. If `A` is the set `{1,2}` and `B` the set `{1}` then the functions:

```
f :: A -> B
f = const 1

g :: B -> A
g 1 = 1
```

have the relation `f . g = id` but not the relation `g . f = id`. A counterexample is

```
g (f 2) = 1
```

---

It turns out that if you have two functions such that `f . g = id` and `g . f = id` then that says a whole lot about the domain and codomain of those functions. In particular, it establishes an isomorphism which suggests that those two domains are in some sense equivalent.

From a category theoretic perspective it means that they are indistinguishable via the morphisms of the category. Category theory emphasizes that the morphisms of the category are the only way to gain information about an object, so this indistinguishability is very important.

When you've got only one-sided inverses, you still are learning a lot about the two domains... but simply not that they're isomorphic.

---

One thing a one-sided inverse gives you is an idempotent. An idempotent is a function `i` from a domain to itself (an endomorphism) such that `i . i = i`. Given any two functions where `f . g = id`, `g . f` is an idempotent and the proof is quite obvious:

```
i . i = (g . f) . (g . f) = g . f . g . f = g . (f . g) . f = g . f = i
```

---

Another good thing to think about is that every function `f :: A -> B` produces the "inverse-image" function `inv f :: B -> (A -> Bool)`.

```
inv :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> b -> a -> Bool
inv f b a = f a == b
```

In more mathematical terms, the inverse image function is a mapping from the codomain `B` to subsets of the domain `A` such that every element in each such subset of `A` maps to the same element of `B`. These subsets partition `A` (this is the definition of a function).

If we have another function `g :: B -> A` such that `g b` is in the subset `inv f b` (i.e. `inv f b (g b) == True` for all `b`) then we have

```
f . g == id
```

but this is far weaker and more technical than `A` and `B` just being isomorphic. It just means that `g` is sending elements of `B` to subsets of `A` which `f` will send right back.

For instance, it admits a whole interesting notion of the ["fibration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) of a space.

Comment: So, you are essentially modding elements of `A` by what they map to in `B`, i.e. considering two elements of `A` to be equal if their images in `B` are equal, which makes for a trivial isomorphism. What does that have to do with fibrations?

Comment: I'm not yet considering them equal, however, any function's inverse image produces a partitioning of its domain. Partitions form equivalence relations and you can then consider what happens to the domain when you take the partition's equivalence relation as truth. This is called a quotient set. Fibrations are a special case of this where each partition shares the same shape and this divides the domain into a bundle of "fibers".

Comment: Oh, and yes! If you do take the quotient group of the domain under the inverse images of the codomain then that quotient group is injective into the codomain. I elided talking about functions where A doesn't map into all of B, though it was tacitly handled in my conditions on `g`. If you finally note that A is surjective into this quotient you'll have the Canonical Decomposition theorem: all functions can be decomposed into a surjection, an isomorphism, and an injection.

Answer (score 3):

If `g :: X -> Y` is surjective, then there is not necessarily a reverse function `f :: Y -> X`. Yet, a surjective function `g` can reverse some function `f`.

[image: g maps X to Y, which reverses some function f from Y to X, shown in orange]

Suppose for every `y` in **`Y`** there is a unique value `x` in **`X`** that `f` finds. It is feasible to specify a function `g` that for every such `x` in **`X`** finds `y` in **`Y`** such that `g . f == id`. This statement shows existence of unique `x` for all `y`, but this does not tell anything about existence of unique `y` for all `x` (i.e. the uniqueness is not guaranteed). (I am not even touching how `g` is built - you'd need axiom of choice).

Comment: (it might be easier with pictures, for some ppl ...)

Answer (score 3):

Using your own example, `myRead . myShow ≡ id`, but

```
(myShow . myRead) "0xFF" = "255"
```

so `myShow . myRead ≢ id`, and you could also see this by a counting argument:

The type `Int` has finitely many values while `String` has infinitely many, so while it is possible to go from `Int` to `String` and back, going from the infinite type `String` to the finite type `Int` must discard information, so you can't always get back to the original string and therefore it is impossible to construct an isomorphism between `Int` and `String`.